# Passar informações da controller(action) para uma função jquery e vice versa

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Uma função jquery chamará uma tela modal, no momento do change de uma **DropDownList**. Quando eu fizer o change, o valor do `id` deverá ser enviado para a **Action** lá então é feito um cálculo e o resultado é enviado para a **jquery**. Logo essa **jquery**, pega esse resultado e verifica, caso o valor seja 0(zero), então o Modal é exibido, contrário não. Estou tentando montar essa **jquery**, apenas o início da mesma, mas não sei como pegar no **call back** da função **jquery**. Tudo nessa função são tentativas, elas não está completa e nem correta, imagino.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#faturarParaDrop').change(function () {
            var $div = $('#modalPartial');
            $.ajax({
                url: '',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (dados) {
                    alert(dados);
                    $div.html(dados);
                    alert(2);
                },
                error: function (erro) {
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

Essa é a **Controller** que fará o cálculo e receberá o parâmetro da jquery. Ainda não coloquei o parâmetro, por ter dúvidas em como fazer e a **var qry** falta terminar para devolver 0 ou outro valor e na **jquery** se 0 exibo senão segue o fluxo.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult FaturarPara(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.Order = _orderService.GetById(CurrentReseller.Id, CurrentCustomer.CustomerGuid, id);

            var options = _orderService.ListarFaturarParaOptions(CurrentReseller.Id, CurrentCustomer.CustomerGuid, id);

            var customer = _customerService.ListCustomerByReseller(CurrentReseller.Id);

            var qry = customer.Where(x => x.Type == CustomerTypeRequest.Customer);

            return View(options);
        }
```

Como eu passo e pego valor numa **jquery** por **call back** e controller(action)?

**EDIT1**

Alterando a jquery para essa, eu pego o ID da dropdownlist. Com esse parâmetro, posso então fazer minha query. Agora, como retorno para a jquery o valor retornado da query, para eu chame ou não o modal?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#faturarParaDrop').change(function () {
            var $div = $('#modalPartial'); //exibir a modal
            var $idcustomer = $(this).val(); //valor do id da dropdownlist
            $.ajax({
                url: '',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({ idcustomer: $idcustomer }),
                success: function (dados) {
                    alert(dados);
                    $div.html(dados);
                    alert(2);
                },
                error: function (erro) {
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

A Action na Controller está assim

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FaturarPara(OrderFaturarParaOptions model, int idcustomer)
        {
            var order = _orderService.SalvarFaturarPara(CurrentReseller.Id, CurrentCustomer.CustomerGuid, model);
            var customer = _customerService.ListCustomerByReseller(CurrentReseller.Id);

            var qry = customer.Where(x => x.Type == CustomerTypeRequest.Customer && x.CustomerId == model.CustomerId)
                                 .Select(x => x.CompanyName ).FirstOrDefault();

            return RedirectToAction("GetOrderDetail", "SearchOrders", new { id = model.OrderId });
        }
```

Comment: E o que dessa action você quer retornar para a view, a `options`?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, eu gostaria de retornar apenas um valor, que seria o qry, depois da query estar totalmente montada, tipo qry = 0 ou qry = 3,45 e assim por diante. Esse valor é que vai disparar ou não o Modal

Comment: Baseado na resposta do Leandro, acho que post na jquery, para o que eu quero, não via dar certo. Mudei para GET, mas o parâmetro não chega na Action

Comment: A questão toda é que eu roteio a jquery passando,**controller/action_name** e não acontece nada. Se tento pegar outra Action dentro da minha controller, não rola, não funciona, só que a jquery está dentro da View XPTO. Isso tem influência?

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer retornar o html renderizado da view, basta utilizar o método load()...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#faturarParaDrop').change(function () {
        $('#modalPartial').load('sua_url/?id=id_selecionado');
    });
});
```

Comment: Uma dúvida. Essa controller tem duas Actions(Get e Post). Quando a tela sobe, consome o método GET. E quando o botão Submit é pressionado, aí eu consumo o método Post. No caso do change da DropDownList, devo realmente usar o Get ou não ou tanto faz?

Comment: Via de regra, é simples... se você está requisitando informações do servidor é GET, se está enviando é POST (e suas variações PUT, PATCH, DELETE e etc) ...

Comment: Entendi, mas no meu caso, eu envio um parâmetro(Value da DropDownList) e recebo o resultado de um cálculo na Action. Esse entendimento é que está me incomodando.

Comment: Minha enorme dificuldade é que com Get ou Post, no success da função eu tenho o dados, por exemplo, e nele eu pego um Html(da página) e eu preciso pegar é apenas o retorno de uma query e é isso que não sei como fazer.

Comment: retorno de qual query?

Comment: Acho que se retornar View, sempre vai dar esse pau. devo alterar a Action para retornar um json, correto? A query que está dentro da Action